# Difference between "been to" and "been in"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

In the following two examples, what is the difference between the usage of *been to* and *been in*? They seem like they have the same meaning but I’m not sure.

> -Have you ever ***been to*** Florida?
>   -Yes, I’ve *been to* Florida many times.
>
> ---
>
> -Have you ever ***been in*** Florida?
>   -Yes, I’ve *been in* Florida many times.

Comment: If you were born in Florida and never left then you've been *in* Florida but never been *to* Florida.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully But in that case no-one would have to ask you if you'd ever been in Florida. Unlike the other respondents,  I would say the two questions are identical unless there is something in the context which raises the lexical contrast to a semantic level.

Comment: @StoneyB Have you ever been *in* Florida?

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully Cunning fellow, I see where you're going (and it's not to Florida). I withdraw with respect to remote communications. As a matter of fact, yes, I've been to Florida many times.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Been to* indicates that you are talking about trips or journeys specifically to Florida. *To* is a preposition of motion and you are talking about movement towards, and arrival in, Florida.

*Been in* connotes a stay in Florida (which may be short, or very long, or simply passing through). *In* denotes position, and you are talking about the state or condition of being located in Florida. It doesn't matter whether you took a trip there or not.

Answer (score 16):

- "He has gone to Paris" means he's there or on his way (to Paris).
- "He has been to Paris" means he's visited Paris (but he's back now).
- "He has been in Paris for two months" means he's in Paris now (and has been for the past two months).

Answer (score 7):

The verb *be* has different meanings in the two examples. In the first example, *be* is used with the meaning *to go* (and *leave*). In the second, it is being used in its more basic sense of *existence*, or in this case, *living in* or *staying in* a location. The two examples can be reworded as:

> Q: Have you ever *visited* Florida?
>
> A: Yes, I've visited Florida many times.
>
> Q: Have you ever *lived in* Florida?
>
> A: Yes, I lived there for two years when I was a kid.

I believe that the use of *many times* in the OP's second example is inconsistent.

Comment: I disagree that *been in* implies a stay. Sometimes, it is rather the reverse: if I fly DFW-MIA-SAV and never leave the terminal  during my layover, I have incontrovertibly been *in* Florida, but could not say I had been *to* it.

Comment: @choster That's simply splitting hairs. Besides, in that case, you could just as well have _been through_ Florida :)

Comment: @choster - If you were asked whether you had *been in Florida* and you answered simply "yes" based on a terminal layover, the questioner would feel deceived.

Comment: While *many times* may be slightly unidiomatic, I am often in London. Most times, I am only in London for a day, if that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Quite so. But, it doesn't really work as, "Have you often been in London?" or "Have you been in London often?". OTOH, "Have you been in London long?" sounds better. But it changes the meaning of the question quite markedly. The Q&A of "Have you ever been in London?" and "Yes, I've often been in London." also sounds odd.

Comment: @bib Such a questioner, presumably, would not understand the tours they offered in northwest Thailand for a bus trip to Burma, where tourists could walk over the border, get their passport stamped, peruse mediocre handcrafts, and return just to say that they had been *in* Myanmar.

Comment: The oddness of "Yes, I've often been in London" depends on context. How about, "Yes, I've often been in London; I **know** the buses are uncomfortable!"? *In* does not need to imply a long stay.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That certainly sounds better, albeit a touch implausible. In any case, as you will note from my answer, I was using _living in_ or _staying in_ to **demonstrate** the use of _to be_ to imply _existence_ (poor choice of word, perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

As a English student with Spanish as mother tongue, it was extremely difficult for me to cope with the idea of "be + to" because "to be" refers inevitably to a location, a place where I am in. On the other hand, verbs of motion like "to go", "to travel"; "to run" express direction and movement towards one direction and this is always expressed with "to". So, this mixed-form "been to + location" was an nightmare for me. My trick to learn it was considering that the verb "visit" as an elided verb. For example. Have you ever been (to visit) Australia?

Comment: But the *to* in *been to* is a preposition; the *to* in *to visit* is a particle in the infinitive form of the verb. In your sentence "Have you even been [to visit] Australia" the *to* changes its part of speech.