# Why do we say “been to” instead of “been in”?

Tags: prepositions, semantics, particles

Why is the particle "to" sometimes used in sentences with *been*?

For example, the following sentences are grammatically correct

- Dad **is in** the garden.
  A: “Where's Dad?”
  B: ”He's **in** the garden”
  A: “How long has he *been* there?”
  B: “He's *been* **in** the garden for about an hour.”

If the location is a foreign country and we use the past participle of the verb *go*, the preposition changes. Note that the preposition reverts back to *in* when it is clear that "dad" is not back from Australia.

- Dad **is** visiting Australia
  C: “Where is your dad?”
  D: “He's gone **to** Australia”
  C: “How long has he **been** there?”
  D: “He's *been* **in** Australia since December 20”

But if someone asks whether he has ever visited Australia,
the preposition used with *been* must be **to**.

1. Has your dad ever been **to** Australia? (= Has he ever visited Australia?)
2. Yes, he's been **to** Australia twice. (= He's visited Australia twice)
3. Is he **in** Australia now?
4. Yes, he's **been** away for about a week.

RETURN HOME

- 5: Where has he been?
  6: He's been **to** Australia for Christmas.

**Question**: Why is the preposition "to", instead of "in", for sentences 1, 2 and 6 above?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77603/difference-between-been-to-and-been-in - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296344/i-have-been-to-france-vs-i-have-been-in-france

Comment: The answer to your specific question is: In sentences 1, 2 and 3 the idea is: in English, we say to go to a place, and, in the past only, to "have been to a place" means to have gone there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Sentences 1, 2 and 6 use the preposition *to* because, in those examples, the verb *been* represents the verb *GO*. The verb *GO* often takes *to*-Complements. We (usually) say *go to a place* because a *to*-preposition phrase represents a *destination* or *goal*.

In the other sentences the verb *been* represents the verb *BE*. The verb *BE* often takes *in*-phrases. *In*-phrases most often represent a location, not a destination (in standard Englishes).

---

**Full answer**

The word *been* can be one of two verbs in English. It can be a past participle of *GO* or it can be a past participle of *BE*.

When we use *GO* in present perfect constructions, we use the participle  *gone* to indicate just going, and the participle *been* to indicate  going and coming back.

7. Bob's gone to Paris.
8. Bob's been to Paris.

Sentence (7) implies that Bob is still in Paris but sentence (8) implies that he is back again.

The verb *GO* normally, but by no means always, takes a *to*-preposition phrase as a Complement. Here the *to*-preposition phrase indicates a GOAL of the original journey.

The verb *BE* often takes *in*-preposition phrases. In such cases, the *in*-preposition phrase indicates a (usually stationary) LOCATION but does not necessarily invoke any idea of movement, goal or end-point.

Let's take two past simple sentences using the verbs *GO* and *BE*:

7. My friend **went to** Sardinia.
8. My friend **was in** Sardinia.

If we change these sentences so that we have present perfect verb forms we get:

9. My friend has **been to** Sardinia.
10. My friend has **been in** Sardinia.

---

**The Original Poster's examples**

> 1. Has your dad ever been to Australia?
> 2. Yes, he's been to Australia twice.
> 3. He's been to Australia for Christmas.

The three examples above all illustrate the use of *been* as the past participle of the verb *GO*. The past simple of these sentences would be:

- Did your Dad ever go to Australia?
- Yes, he went to Australia twice.
- He went to Australia for Christmas.

Examples (1-3), like the past simple sentences above, use the preposition *to* to indicate the goal of the movement. These *to*-preposition phrases are selected specifically because of the verb *GO* here.

We can contrast these sentences with the other examples from the Original Post:

3. Is he in Australia now?
4. Yes, he's been away for about a week.
5. Where has he been?

The past simple versions of these sentences would be:

- Was he in Australia (then)?
- Yes, he was away for about a week.
- Where was he?

We can see that these sentence all use the verb *BE*. They take a range of preposition phrase Complements, headed by the prepositions *in, away* and *where* respectively. These preposition phrases, as is common with the verb *BE*, all indicate a location as opposed to a goal.

Interestingly, the Original Poster's last two examples, (5) and (6) use different *been*s, arguably different verbs:

> 5: Where has he been?
> 6: He's been to Australia for Christmas.

The past simple version of this conversation would be:

- Where was he?
- He went to Australia for Christmas.

Notice that the speaker of (6) could have said:

- He's been in Australia.

The past simple version of this would be:

- He was in Australia.

Hope this has ***been*** interesting!

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure how to answer your question as you have put it.

The usage goes back a fair way.  For example, we have the traditional nursery rhyme:  “Pussy cat, Pussy cat, where have you been?/I’ve been up to London to visit the Queen.”. So the usage is well established.

It is worth saying that in the Somerset dialect (county in the U.K.) you say not “where is he?”, but “where’s he to?”

So a starting point might be to say that, if it makes sense to say that someone is *in* a place, then it can make sense to say that someone is to a place.  It just so happens that as a matter of general usage, people just don’t.  Except in Somerset, and there only in questions. And everyone else in the past tense.

In fact, when we consider further, we all do something similar in the present tense.  “I’m off to the City.”. Perhaps this is a kind of ellipse for “I am starting/setting off for the city.”

What is certainly the case is that the wide and varied use of prepositions to create and modify meaning is a marked feature of the English language as compared with many other languages.

So is the use of the verb *to be*.  There is a joke that illustrates this.  A meeting of three people has been arranged in a pub for noon.  One arrives early at 11:30.  A second arrives late at twenty past twelve.  He says to the first:  “Where’s Tommy?”. The first replies:  “I think he’s been and gone and hasn’t come.”.

The joke arises from the two conflicting possible meanings.  The first uses ‘has been’ in the sense of ‘has been  and ‘gone .  So, on this interpretation, the speaker contradicts himself - talks nonsense.  But in fact his is a special usage of ‘been and’ and ‘gone and’ with a main verb.

Here you see special colloquial usages of the past tenses of both *to be* and *to go*.  In both cases the addition of *and* in some way modifies the main action, indicating that it is a dreadful *faut pas*.  So a child scribbles on the new wallpaper.  Her brother might say:  “You’ve gone and done it now.”, or “You’ve been and done it now.”.  This indicates the recognition that they are in trouble, or, as her brother could just as well have said:  “Umm: you’re really *for* it now.”.  When you put *been and* together with *done and*, the misdeed or *faut pas*. is even worse.

I am not sure to what extent systematic grammatical analysis of so wide and free a range of usage of prepositions and the ‘blank’ verbs /*be*, *go* and *do* is either possible or even desirable.  I am sure that it is an example (one among many) of the amazing flexibility of the English language.

Back with (*see, there we go again!*) your original question, the usage is a function not just of the preposition *to* or *in* but of its combination with the verb *to be* in the past tense.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the various prepositions is the various meanings of "to be", as the OED explains:

> Etymology: The paradigm of the verb ‘to be’ in West Germanic languages in general shows forms derived from three unrelated Indo-European bases, *in English itself perhaps [the] forms derived from **four** Indo-European bases*.

The four Old English verbs each have a complex history based on the regional version of English; the indicative and subjunctive; the stress or lack of it, and other factors.

The full history of the verb **to be** is far too complex to describe here (and describing it any less than "fully" would not help your understanding.) You should do your own research if you are really interested. However, all the senses have been retained:

It is red - lexically empty copula.

Wait until it is ripe = becomes, (related to "The king is to London" = goes)

I was in Paris = to stay, remain, spend time.

There are lions in Africa = exist

The meaning that is used will determine which preposition is used.